Using NavigationLink(destination:, label:) and .navigationDestination in the same app breaks Navigation Stack
In an app I'm working on, NavigationStack is created at the App level with Screen 1 as the root.
Screen 1 has a NavigationLink with destination and label parameters. On tapping the NavigationLink, the user is taken to Screen 2. Screen 2 has a .navigationDestination pointing to Screen 3.
I expected Screen 3 to be presented without any issues, but what happens is that Screen 3 is visible for a split second and then Screen 2 is show on the screen. When I tap the navigation bar back button on Screen 2, Screen 3 is visible, and if I tap the back button on this screen, I'm taken to Screen 1.
Upon further tests, a NavigationLink(destination:, label:) followed by .navigationDestination always causes this issue, not vice-versa.
Here's the code producing this issue:
struct Screen3: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Fourth()) {
                Text("Screen 3")
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Screen 3")
    }
}

struct Screen2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(value: 0) {
                Text("Screen 2" )
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { int in
            Screen3()
        }.navigationTitle("Screen 2")
    }
}

struct Screen1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Screen2()) {
            Text("Screen 1")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Screen 1")
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        Screen1()
    }
}

How do I use both NavigationLinks and .navigationDestination without breaking the NavigationStack they're used on?

I think that you put the navigation too deep in the navigation stack so it can not see it when building the first navigation level.

Sounds similar to What is the solution to this NavigationStack glitch?. The two kinds of navigation link don't mix well, perhaps it's time to migrate all of your links?
